# Limited a user with creating rbash, exporting the path in .bashrc but /bin/ls still works

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, restriction

I tried limiting ls command to a specific user. It works, but when I execute /bin/ls, it executes successfully again, how to restrict here.

```
useradd -m $username -s /bin/rbash
echo "$username:$password" | chpasswd
mkdir /home/$username/bin
chmod 755 /home/$username/bin
echo "PATH=$HOME/bin" >> /home/$username/.bashrc
echo "export PATH" >> /home/$username/.bashrc
ln -s /bin/ls /home/$username/bin/
```

Comment: What is the intended restriction? Is only `$username` allowed to execute the `ls` command, and other users must not execute `ls`? Or is this user restricted to this single command?

Comment: Yes. `$username` is allowed to execute only `ls` command which I'm allowing to. Others are not in the picture.

Comment: You might have made `rbash` the login shell, but if the user can execute `/bin/ls`, they aren't actually running a restricted shell.

Comment: @chepner So how do I make it run in restricted shell?